# About the cummulative distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I create a column called log returns. They follow the Gaussian distribution that's why we can use the PDF and CDF for analysis. I also create a column price difference which is just the normal version of the log returns. Now, I calculate quantities. Like if 95% quantile of the price difference is 38, that means 95% of the price differences lie below 38. Now if I use the CDF at 95% quantile of the log return, that would give me the probability of the stock price being below 38. If I calculate it at -95% quantile, it will tell me the probability of the stock price being below -38 Rs. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: You need some assumptions (Stationarity, ergodicity...)

Comment: There is a function that evaluates the CDF at a given point but that point should be a quantile. If the 0.05 quantile is -28 and I calculate -0.05 quantile, will I get the probability of x being less than or equal to 28? The minus signs in the quantile and quantile value will get multiplied?

Comment: I dont really follow.